# Is there way to check the file size in ejs?

Tags: javascript, ejs, filesize

> I have a image located in my folder while showing front end i want to
>   check that size if file size is zero i want to show media is not
>   found.

```
  if(fileSize!=0)
    {

    <li class="message left appeared"><div class="text_wrapper"><div class="text"><img src="/public/images/abc.png" style="width:400px;"></div></div></li>


    }
    else
    {
    media is not found
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889948/applying-javascript-to-check-file-size-and-extension

Comment: it is when we are uploading. But in my case file is already uploaded and  i have to fetch the file in folder and find the size of that file